# How to find the right window - Process Win 32 VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winapi, process, find, window

I used Spy++ to visualize a software's window structure. However, I realized that the program has several windows with the same name, as shown in the image below. How to make reference to each of the highlighted windows?

Edit: The windows have the same name and the classes too.

[image: Spy++]

Comment: Windows have names. And classes. If the names are identical, use the window class to discriminate.

Comment: The problem is exactly that. The windows have the same name and the classes too.

Comment: With both [EnumChildWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumchildwindows) and UI Automation's [AutomationElement.FindAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.findall), you can get all the `SysListView32` class objects. Then you can determine which is which by its content (or the Parent's) or whatever else you're looking for (some are not visible).